# How to show record after joining from two tables in a Single View in ASP.net MVC Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to show records after joining from two tables and display it on a view i have recently started working on MVC Entity framework and do not know how to do it. One table is Employee and the other one is Department :

Department

```
Dept_id
Emp_id
Dept_Name
Salary
```

Employee

```
Emp_id
Emp_Name
Emp_Address
Emp_Contact
```

I want to show Particular Employee Name, Address, Contact, Salary and Department Details in a Single View i.e. EmployeeDetails. I have previously worked on retrieving a particular record from a single table as below.

```
 public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
         var query = dbquery.Employee.First(c => c.Emp_id == id);
         return View(query);
    }
```

Thanks for your answers....

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't quite understand your question. Do you have problems designing the view or structuring the data. If it's the second i would suggest creating a ViewModel that contains all the data you need to display and send it to the view.

Comment: I want to display data in a view from two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use query syntax as follow

```
var query= (from x in dbquery.Employee join y in dbquery.Department on x.Emp_id equals y.Emp_id 
     where x.Emp_id==id  select new {x.Emp_id, x.Emp_name,x.Emp_Address,x.Emp_Contact, y.dept_id,y.dept_name,y.salary}).ToList(); return View(query);
```

it will fetch data from two tables. now on view use following loop

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
        {
            <li>item.Emp_Id</li>
            <li>item.Emp_Name</li>
            <li>item.Emp_Address</li>
             <li>item.Emp_Contact</li>
            <li>item.dept_id</li>
            <li>item.dept_name</li>
            <li>item.salary</li>
        }
```

it's better you design an model class for these attributes and bind your view with this model

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I want to know whether it will extract a particular record or whole list of record from a table.

Comment: it will fetch all records having id given in your ActionMethod as parameter. If id is unique in database, then definitely it will fetch a single record only

Comment: It is extracting the records, but the properties are inaccessible inside view, i have used @model IEnumerable<MvcApp.Models.dbEntities>

Comment: the error i get is The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`6[System.Int32,System.String,....'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MvcApp.Models.dbEntities]'.

Comment: try to make a model class having properties emp_id,name,address,contact,deptid,deptname and salary. say it is empinfo class then in controll make list of this class and loop over result of query and initialize this array and sent to view and in view write this line @model List<Models.empinfo>. hope it will work